# Is it possible to change PID parameters of 6 motors silmutaneously(in a single launch file)?)

Tags: dynamixel, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, i'm trying to control a 6 dof robot arms using 6 dynamixel motors(MX series). The only way i know to tune PID parameters is to launch dynamixel_workbench_single_manager. However, i may only tune the parameters one by another and cause a time-waste. So i'm searching a way to tune multi-motors parameters. Is it possible or where can i find the source to realize this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283697/is-it-possible-to-change--pid-parameters-of-6-motors-silmutaneously(in-a-single-launch-file)?)/) by [ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33870/ryan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-02-26**:
Can you be more specific ? Like do you want to share the same configuration with all your motors ? It looks like you have to create a launch file to define all your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :)

Thank you for your inquiry about dynamixel_workbench.

You can change parameters of multi-dynamixels using SyncWrite function.

If you look at line 56 in [torque control example](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench/blob/master/dynamixel_workbench_controllers/src/torque_control.cpp), 'Goal_Current' parameter are added to syncwrite handler. You can change it as 'P_Gain' or 'D_Gain' and write gain to the dynamixels by syncWrite function simultaneously.(line 152 in same example)

Best regards
Darby

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-02-26**:
Well this [launch](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench/blob/master/dynamixel_workbench_controllers/launch/torque_control.launch) isn't doing what you want ?

**Comment by [ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33870/ryan/) on 2018-03-01**:
Thanks a lot :)) However, i have just encountered another error. When i launch the [torque_control](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench_controllers/Tutorials/TorqueControl) file, after the model and id popped out, the process died immediately. How come?? :(

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-02**:
What are you launching exactly ? torque_control.cpp or torque_control.launch ?

**Comment by [ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33870/ryan/) on 2018-03-02**:
torque_control.launch exactly.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-02**:
Well since it's just a simple launcher for the torque node it means that you might have a problem with your parameters, check with `ls /dev/input` if your devices are well connected.